# Rails: Add params to response without migrating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller that was generated by Ruby CLI for db migration with following columns:

```
  def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(
      :code,
      :name,
      :description,
      :offered
    )
  end
```

I want to add a logic something like:

```
if course.offered.include? "spring"
    course.next_offered = "1-5"
end
```

so that I can use `course.next_offered` in my `_course.html.erb`. I don't want to add a column to my database since this is a class project and my professor wanted me to do so.

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you want a helper. But is `next_offered` data that has to be store? It is unclear if your teacher wanted you to do a migration or not.

Comment: Basically, I want to add a new attribute to `@course` without creating a new column in the table. What I want to do is the same as add a new key:value to a json. I'm a rail beginner so that's basically what I understand.

Comment: Why do you need an "attribute"? Why not just call the method and have it return the value? e.g. `def next_offered; '1-5' if course.offered.include? "spring"; end`

Answer (score 0):

Check out virtual attributes ( aka: attr_accessor ) - https://jtway.co/rails-virtual-attributes-use-cases-cf33bd45e2a4